# Show a google map inside a dialogfragment in a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I want to load a map inside a dialog fragment that is loaded from a fragment.

When I do this using an activity, it is working fine, the map is displayed and it is fully functioning.
However, when I do this inside a fragment, the map only shows a grey fragment with a google logo on the bottom left.

I have browsed everywhere and almost got a similar answer for checking my google API key. However, the API key is just working fine with the other project. I also tried changing it, but of no help.

Here is my code:
**map_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose your location"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Long click the marker pin or click anywhere on map"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    tools:context=".ngo.NgoHomeActivity"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <customfonts.MyEditText
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColorHint="#000"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    android:id="@+id/etAddress"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSaveAddress"
                    android:text="SAVE ADDRESS"
                    android:background="@drawable/angle"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MapDialogFragment.java**

```
public class MapDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    Address address;
    StringBuffer addressDetails;
    List<Address> addresses;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    Marker marker;

    Location currentLocation;
    LatLng latLng;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    double latitude, longitude;
    String nAddLine2;
    View rootView;
    EditText edAddress;
    Button btnSaveAdd;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_dialog,container,false);
        edAddress = rootView.findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        btnSaveAdd = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveAddress);
        btnSaveAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
        fetchLastLocation();
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap = googleMap;
        CameraPosition newCamPos = new CameraPosition(latLng,
                15.5f,
                mMap.getCameraPosition().tilt, //use old tilt
                mMap.getCameraPosition().bearing); //use old bearing
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newCamPos), 4000, null);
//        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,10));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), latLng.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try{
                    latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                    longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                }catch (Exception IOException) {
                    IOException.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Error Message:", IOException.getMessage());
                    Log.e("", "Error in getting address for the location");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Couldn't get address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0){
                    Log.e("","Error in getting address for the location");

                }else{
                    String receivedAddress = getAddress();
                    showResults(receivedAddress);
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));
                }
            }
        });
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));
    }

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {

                    currentLocation = location;
//                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), location.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapDialogFragment.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    fetchLastLocation();
                }
        }
    }

    public String getAddress(){

    }

    private void showResults(String currentAdd) {


    }
}
```

and the button clcik event from fragment that launched the dialog fragment:

```
edNAddLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new MapDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(),null);
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: So i understand that your map is grayed out? Do you get any errors? And to clarify, the map that works is in another Android project and you use the same API key in both projects? Is your key restricted?

Comment: No.The key is not restricted.

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the problem on my own. The problem was with the fragment only. 
Because I tried launching the map inside an activity and it was working just fine.

For anyone who encounters the problem, I changed the following statement:

```
dialogFragment.show(Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()),null);
```

Where the key was: Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager).

I don't know however, what does that do. Answers appreciated.